# populating AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do i populate an AlertDialog using ArrayList?? any help will be appreciated.. thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please, more clear in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ArrayAdapter` for your `ArrayList`. Then, use `setAdapter()` on `AlertDialog.Builder`.